# The conflict is caused by: The user requested tensorboard==1.12.2 and tensorflow==1.12.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

```
PS D:\New folder (2)\TamilChatbot-banking-service\Chatbot-banking-service-master\rasa_nlu> pip install -r requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: elasticsearch==6.3.1 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.3.1
)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo==3.7.2 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-crfsuite==0.9.6 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.9
.6)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML==3.13 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (3.13)        
Requirement already satisfied: rasa-core==0.13.0 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rasa-core-sdk==0.12.1 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.12
.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rasa-nlu==0.14.1 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rocketchat-API==0.6.25 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (0.6
.25)
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml==0.15.87 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (0.15.
87)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn==0.20.2 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.20
.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.2.0 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (0
.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy==2.0.18 in c:\users\abise\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (2.0.18)    
Collecting tensorboard==1.12.2
  Using cached tensorboard-1.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (3.0 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (from versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0,
 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2
, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc
0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.
3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
```

I change tensorboard==1.12.3 and  tensorflow==1.13.1

Comment: This is only the stacktrace, Please add more details like your code and what you are trying to achieve. I have upvoted your question as it is a valid issue which I also faced from time to time. But others here are not so lenient like me, they might close it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Python version is 3.7 but tensorboard 1.12.2 supports Python :: 2.7, 3.4 - 3.6. If you want to use this older version of tensorboard, You may have to downgrade your python to a supported version and then `pip install tensorboard==1.12.2`. Alternatively, you can `pip install tensorboard==2.10.0` as `tensorboard 2.10.0` supports Python 3.7.
Note that the stable release doesn't currently support Python 3.7. See the [release history](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/#history) of tensorboard and its requirements.